# API response is html and not Json

Tags: json, api, curl, postman

I am trying to connect to FortiSandbox api, [guide here](https://docs.fortinet.com/uploaded/files/2684/fortisandbox-2.1.1-rest-api-guide.pdf).

Snippet from guide:

[image]

My username: admin

My password: Aa12345!

**cURL:**

```
    curl -X POST \
  https://10.1.1.170/sys/login/user/ \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'postman-token: bd3ae694-f400-c723-8955-bfc4e96c8147' \
  -d '{
  "method": "exec",
  "params": [{
    "url": "/sys/login/user/",
    "data": [{
      "user": "admin",
      "passwd": "Aa12345!"
    }]
  }],
  "id": 1,
  "ver": "2.0"
}'
```

The respone is HTML instead of Json, [here full HTML content response](https://codeshare.io/alQ0QD)

plz give advices to desperate person
Some of the HTML response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>FortiSandbox - Please login</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: Codeshare is down

Comment: Please include all info relevant to your problem directly in your question, not on external sites that might go down at any time.

Comment: Considering that the `title` element of this HTML document says, “FortiSandbox - Please login”, you likely have something wrong with the authentication of your request.

Comment: It appears that the log in request is using EXEC as the method (more standard GET and POST are also present. Have you tried using Chrome and Devtools to look at the traffic between browser and log-in method?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt what do you mean please.

Comment: @CBroe thank's for replay, but when I login manually that's my username and password

Comment: Well then probably either your request is not in the right format yet, or you are not sending it to the correct endpoint.

Comment: The login doc says "method":"exec", the others say "method":"GET" or "method":"POST". Your CURL uses POST. I can't find any reference to an EXEC method in the docs - but it may be that the API does recognize the HTTP Verb, and is therefore responding with HTML.

Comment: And if you read the Python script above "Basic Python script to access FortiSandbox information through web interface.", it shows you can also log in using a standard browser - by inspecting the HTTP traffic, you may be able to work out what's going on. Devtools in Chrome has a "copy as CURL" option to make it even easier!

Comment: @NevilleKuyt I have tried to catch the login request, I watched [this guide](https://www.alexkras.com/copy-any-api-call-as-curl-request-with-chrome-developer-tools/), but all the response I see it's html and css, not Json

Comment: As per Jp FernandeZ's answer, the endpoint should always be {ip}/jsonrpc
This is what I was doing wrong. After that the JSON Api guide actually started making sense. There is NO mention of jsonrpc in the guide!

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -X POST http://10.1.1.170/jsonrpc -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'postman-token: bd3ae694-f400-c723-8955-bfc4e96c8147' -d '{"method": "exec","params": [{"url": "/sys/login/user","data": [{"user": "admin","passwd": "Aa12345!"}]}],"id": 1,"ver": "2.0"}'
```

Comment: Dear Jp FernandeZ, it would be nice if you post some additional comments besides of bare code to clarify your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue w/ Microsoft Business Central.  I added the Accept: application/json to the header and now is working - getting back json response